# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento, model

I am a new to Magento and in learning process. I am getting this error when loading a model. Here's my code. Any help deeply appreciated

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Pfay_Test>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Pfay_Test>
 </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
        <routeurfrontend>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                <frontName>test</frontName>
            </args>
        </routeurfrontend>
    </routers>
    <layout>
       <updates>
            <test>
                 <file>test.xml</file>
             </test>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
  <global>
      <models>
          <test>
             <class>Pfay_Test_Model</class>
             <resourseModel>test_resource</resourseModel>
         </test>
         <test_resource>
             <class>Pfay_Test_Model_Resource</class>
             <entities>
                 <test>
                   <table>pfay_test</table>
                 </test>
              </entities>
          </test_resource>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <test>
          <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
        </test>
    </blocks>
    <heplers>
        <test>
          <class>Pfay_Test_Hepler</class>
        </test>
    </heplers>
    <resources>
     <test_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </test_write>
   <test_read>
      <connection>
         <use>core_read</use>
      </connection>
   </test_read>
</resources>
</global>
```

Pfay/Test/Model/Test.php

```
 class Pfay_Test_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
      {
           protected function _construct()
          {
            $this->_init('test/test');
       }

    }
```

Pfay/Test/Model/Resource/Test.php

```
   class Pfay_Test_Model_Resource_Test extends  Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{

      protected function _construct()
      {
         $this->_init('test/test', 'id_pfay_test');
       }   

     }
```

Magento/test.php

```
  require_once("app/Mage.php");

 Mage::app();


     $data = Mage::getModel("test/test");
     $data->load(2);
     print_r($data);
```

I get this error
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php on line 225

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `<resourceModel>`, not `<resourseModel>`

Comment: Hi Subroutines, Thank you so much.